# Dynamically set the initial page of page controller on navigation from another screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview builder with Image.network wrapped in an Inkwell as its child. I want to navigate to another page which consists of a page view builder on image clicked. I have passed the index of the list view builder in the constructor. Now I want to dynamically set the value of the initial page of page view builder according to the index of list view which I have passed in the constructor. I tried setting the initial page in  PageController to widget.index but throws an error only static values can be assigned. I also tried pagecontroller.jumptoPage(widget.index) which throws an exception Scroll controller not attached to any scroll views. How can I solve this?

Comment: Any updates on this?  I have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page controller has to be defined on the `initState()` rather than the State class since only static member can be accessed in initializers.

Eg.

```
void initState(){
     pageController=PageController(initialPage:widget.index)
}
```